# Setting activity variables from different activity

Tags: android

I have some major variables in my main activity that I retrieve their values from internet once the user log in. after that, there are multiple activities that can alter these values in the database but this doesn't reflect in the current loaded values until the user log out/in. (the process where I retrieve data from internet)

what is the best way to update these values in main activity from activity 2  directly without logging out/in?

is there a way to set these variables without making intent and putting the new values in extra bundle? ( I need to change the values without returning back to the activity)

Comment: You can use `SharedPreference`

Comment: You can pass the value in an Intent bundle and startActivityForResult. Once you get the activity result callback, you can update if the value has changed

Comment: good one. thanks. how can I change a certain variable value, put the new value with the same key? is that will remove the old value?

Comment: @Nikola, I am sorry but I didn't get your answer, is startingactivityforresult will not move the user interface to the main activity? I need to keep him in his activity and just alter the values

Answer (score 1):

You can perhaps try putting the variables in a custom `Application` class as static members and then access them from anywhere through `Application.xyzStaticMember()`. Here's an example:

```
public class MyTestApp extends Application {
    private static List<Int> testList;
    public static void setList(List<Int> l) {
        testList = l;
    }
    public static List<Int> getList() {
        return testList;
    }
}
```

Then access the members: `MyTestApp.setList(null);` or `MyTestApp.getList();`. Oh, and don't forget to use the class in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file!

```
<application android:name="com.example.MyTestApp" 
/* ...more stuffs */ />
```

Comment: thanks, I will try this. it will be applicable I guess.